# MySQL: How to select rows based on other rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, tags

I'm working with a tag system for an image repository.  I have 3 tables: `images`, `tags`, and `tapMap`.

`images` houses the information for the images
`tags` houses all the tags (each row is unique)
`tagMap` stores the association between images and tags

`tagMap` looks something like this:

```
id    |   img_ID   |   tag_ID
1           22           51
2           22           55
3           25           55
4           27           56
5           30           70
6           30           71
7           31           70
```

What I want to do is be able to grab images that have multiple tags.  So I could have a query with something like `SELECT img_ID FROM tagMap WHERE tag_ID = 51 AND tag_ID = 55`.

The problem is that since each association is stored in a separate row, I can't do that.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
To be clear, I only want to select images with all of the passed tags.  So the query above should only return img_ID 22.

Comment: I'm not really getting the question, maybe use joins?

Comment: or maybe use subqueries?

Comment: If I do that, it will also return images with EITHER of those tags.  I only want images with BOTH.

Comment: If you are looking for only images with BOTH tags, you can accomplish this using subqueries, as @MarceloBezerra suggests.

Comment: @dubstylee how would I go about using subqueries for that?  It needs to be able to support more than just 2 tags.

Comment: why is this question getting downvoted? I think it is a perfectly legitimate question, unless it is a duplicate question.

Comment: Most would have named the junction table `image_tags` instead of `tagMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on the same table more than once:

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM images i
JOIN tagMap tm1
  ON tm1.img_ID = i.img_ID
JOIN tagMap tm2
  ON tm2.img_ID = i.img_ID
WHERE tm1.tag_ID = '51'
  AND tm2.tag_ID = '55'
```

or, if you'd prefer:

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM images i
JOIN tagMap tm1
  ON tm1.img_ID = i.img_ID AND tm1.tag_ID = '51'
JOIN tagMap tm2
  ON tm2.img_ID = i.img_ID AND tm2.tag_ID = '55'
```

Comment: Would this work for every scenario? Say there is a record with 3 or more tags? The join will only join the first 2 tags leaving the last ones not matched.

Comment: You'll need 3 joins for 3 tags.

Comment: You'd need to add the table again - a copy of the table and a join for each tag to be incldued in the where condition

Comment: Seems to be working.  I'll run a few more tests to make sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through 2 subqueries and a INTERSECT of the two.

```sql
SELECT img_ID
FROM tagMap
WHERE tag_ID = 51
INTERSECT
SELECT img_ID
FROM tagMap
WHERE tag_ID = 52;
```

And if you are doing this in mysql, which doesn't support `INTERSECT`, here's one way to do an intersect:

```sql
SELECT t3.img_ID from (
  (SELECT img_ID FROM tagMap WHERE tag_ID = 51) AS t1 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT img_ID FROM tagMap WHERE tag_ID = 52) AS t2 
) AS t3 GROUP BY img_ID HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: That also gives images with *either* tag.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT`.

Comment: wow, no love from anyone... all the answers and question are downvoted. :)

Comment: @dartanian300 - have you tried my latest solution? I think it would work to do what you want to do. I think it is also extendable for searching for more than 2 tags by just incrementing the count number and adding another subquery.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways for some reason, I'm getting a syntax error with that query.  Marcus Adams answer seems to work

Comment: I agree, Marcus's answer is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT img_ID FROM tagMap t1
WHERE tag_ID = 51
  AND exists (select 1 from tagmap t2 where t2.tag_ID = 52 and t2.img_ID = t1.img_ID)
```

Edit: Another option is

```
select t1.img_ID 
from (SELECT * FROM tagMap WHERE tag_ID = 51) t1
inner join (SELECT * FROM tagMap WHERE tag_ID = 52) t2 ON t1.img_id =  t2.img_ID
```

Depending on the number of tags you want to select for and the data volumes one or the other might be easier/faster.  For large data volumes in the tables and large numbers of tags to select for, neither are likely to scale well (for each additional tag you want to include as a condition you need an additional sub select in both cases)

**Addition:**
Another possible solution:

```
SELECT Q.img_id FROM (
    SELECT img_ID, count(1) as num
    FROM tagMap t1
    WHERE tag_ID in (51, 52)
    GROUP BY img_id ) Q 
WHERE Q.num = 2
```

I think this one might well scale best.  To add extra tags simply add to the `in()` condition and increase the number matched by the outer where condition.  E.g.

```
SELECT Q.img_id FROM (
    SELECT img_ID, count(1) as num
    FROM tagMap t1
    WHERE tag_ID in (51, 52, 59)
    GROUP BY img_id ) Q 
WHERE Q.num = 3
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted my answer explain the problem with it?  It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

This will return all images that are having multiple tags

```
//assuming you have id in images table and tags table
SELECT images.id 
FROM images
    INNER JOIN tagMap
        ON tagMap.imgId = images.id
    INNER JOIN tags
        ON tags.id = tagMap.tag_ID
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: as the OP said in his post `What I want to do is be able to grab images that have multiple tags.`

Comment: You'll need to keep reading past that point. The OP is specifying the tags.